# trying to create jira ticket with python

Tags: jira-rest-api

here below a piece of code I wrote that should create a jira ticket on my jira domain.
I created a personal token but for some reason it doesnt work...

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

TOKEN = "KAJSF21DKSAH1KJHFSAN912"

url = "https://cxscompany.jira.com/rest/api/2/"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + TOKEN
}
payload = json.dumps(
    {
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "AUT"
       },
       "summary": "summary mike",
       "description": "description mike",
       "issuetype": {
           "name": "Task"
       }
   }
}
)


response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

pprint(response)
```

I expect a ticket to be created in my jira domain, but I get this error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cxscompany.jira.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/latest/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

Comment: I think your ssl certificate is invalid as per error. Try http instead of https.